# Actions on routes / controllers

Tags: ember.js

I am using:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 2.2.0
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.2.1
DEBUG: jQuery            : 1.11.3
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.0.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

I need to setup a controller when handling an action. I define an action in my application route:

```
// routes/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    filterCategories: Ember.inject.controller('filter-categories'),

    actions: {
        openSubcategory(categoryId, subcategoryId) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

But I get:

> Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Defining an injected controller
>   property on a non-controller is not allowed.

This is documented nowhere (at least I can not find it), but it's ok. I will move the action to the application controller:

```
// controllers/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    filterCategories: Ember.inject.controller('filter-categories'),

    actions: {
        openSubcategory(categoryId, subcategoryId) {
            ...
            return false;
        },
    },

});
```

Now I get:

> Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the action 'openSubcategory'. If you
>   did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from
>   an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.

I am obviously handling the action in the application controller, so that's not true. I am also returning `false` from that action handler, so no bubbling. What could be going on? There is little documentation about actions in the guides, and it's only [component related](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/actions/). What about actions in controllers and routes?

The API documentation talks about actions in [controller](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#property_actions) and routes.On controllers:

> These functions will be invoked when a matching {{action}} is
>   triggered from within a template and the application's current route
>   is this route.

This seems wrong (should be "application's current controller is this controller").

Comment: Actions do not bubble up to parent controllers, they bubble up to parent routes.

Comment: Try to use the controllerFor function instead of injecting the controller.

Comment: "This is documented nowhere (at least I can not find it), but it's ok." -> http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller "Can only be used when defining another controller."

Comment: You can find classic actions documented in [older versions of the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/templates/actions/). We now focus the documentation on closure actions as they are the recommended path.